# Change html element class using JQuery has no effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actually i'm trying to change a class with jquery to a bootstrap badge item.
The item's are generated dynamically so on click of the table item i add to a variable the id of the anchor.

Then i've made 4 functions for each item of popover that you can see on the screen
[image]

Each of the popover anchors as CHIUSO RISOLTO etc. should change the main anchor class of the table item.

Actually i was trying to use something like this to change the class

```
function Risolt() {
    $("#idticket").removeClass();
    $('#idticket').addClass('badge badge-success');
}
```

I think the problem is on setting the id as onClick of table items i've set the following function

```
var idticket
function setId(id) {
    idticket = id
}
```

Comment: what class you want to remove put it as parameter of `removeClass()`

Comment: @JohnKarry can you please add some more code?

Comment: @MaheerAli actually i think the problem is the id as if i set the id manually it's works, added the code where i assign the id to the variable

Comment: @JohnKarry can you add whole code its confusing. please add html with id so i can give you exact solution

Comment: @jigarhalani solved i just had to concatenate the idticket and don't use it like text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED:**

As i was setting of table item click the id to a variable the #idticket simply doesn't exist i just had to concatenate the variable in jquery and not add that as text.

Thank's all for helping.

Comment: That description of the problem makes very little sense given the lack of context in the question. However as it sounds like it was a typographical error unique to your code I'd suggest simply deleting this question as it's unlikely to help any future visitors.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan actually i'm unable to delete it cause of other answers

Answer (score 0):

At first you should replace `$("#idticket").removeClass();` to `$("#idticket").removeAttr('class');`, then add any class you want.

Comment: Calling `removeClass()` without arguments is the correct way to remove all classes on an element. `removeAttr()` is not required, nor is it good practice in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use toggleClass jQuery to switch classes

```
$('#idticket').toggleClass("oldClass newClass");
```